Any simple statistical adjust to pricing?
I rent my car on bunch of market place like qeeq, turo, getaround, lyft. I have seasonality data at the daily level for my market. I’ve set a baseline price for my car. The final price is calculated as: baseline * seasonality * factor. The factor is 1.2 for Fridays, Saturdays, and Sundays, and 1.0 for other days.
I’m also tracking 100 cars listed on a different marketplace, monitoring their prices and whether they secured a reservation for each date.
How can I refine my baseline price to maximize bookings? Currently, I review and adjust my baseline price weekly. In Excel, I have the following columns:
Date My price (= baseline * seasonality * factor) My car's booking status (Boolean) Market median price Market max price Market booking rate (Percentage)
Given this setup, how can I adjust my baseline price to maximize my revenue in statistical sound way, based on the reservations I'm seeing coming in market? In guess work, Sometime I price too low, I get alot of reservations compared to market, if I price too high getting no booking at all.

Can you outsource the problem? Adjusting the baseline price is a fairly simple problem any first year economist should be able to do this for you.

Whom to outsource?

Can you tell in simple words how to do?
